# Узнать размер колонки

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Для того, чтобы узнать размер всей бд, или, например, одной таблицы, у нас есть команда 'sp_spaceused'.
Но если пойти дальше, то возникает вопрос: а как получить статистику по полям? Как узнать, в каком поле (колонке) в таблице содержатся самые тяжёлые данные, а в каком самые легкие?

Вопрос не столько теоретический, сколько практический: есть огромная база, которую надо проанализировать (постепенно погружаюсь в Data-Mining).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте функцию `DATALENGTH()`

В следующем примере находится длина столбца ProductName в таблице MyOrderTable.

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(ProductName) as [SizeInBytes] FROM MyOrderTable
```

Для справки: [DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173486.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

> Как узнать, в каком поле (колонке) в таблице содержатся самые тяжёлые
>   данные, а в каком самые легкие?

Вас интересует размер в байтах, занимаемый тем или иным столбцом на диске (видимо так, раз вы упомянули `sp_spaceused`)?

Не уверен, что возможно определить его точно. Точно можно узнать, сколько *страниц* (блоков по 8Кб, которыми SqlServer хранит данные) занимают данные *всей* таблицы (или индекса).

Месту на диске, отведенному под хранение конкретного столбца, по-видимому можно дать лишь некоторую оценку (которая, впрочем, не всегда будет адекватной). И с `datalength` не совсем всё просто. Далее несколько подробнее.

---

Возьмём запрос

```
/*1*/ select sum(datalength([Column])) from [Table];
```

за основу оценки.

**Во-первых**. Кроме собственно данных столбца всегда есть дополнительная *служебная* информация, которая может иметь отношение к столбцу, но её объем между столбцами логически может делиться непропорционально их количеству в таблице (например данные заголовка строки). Т.е. оценку размера `/*1*/` следует воспринимать как "не менее чем".

Чем меньше в таблице столбцов, и чем короче запись, тем больше издержки на служебные данные, тем, соответственно, дальше оценка `/*1*/` от реальности. Так, для таблицы с одним коротким столбцом полный размер данных (с учётом служебной информации) может значительно превосходить "логический" размер данных самого столбца. Сравните, например, для таблицы

```
create table tiny_nums (value tinyint);

insert into tiny_nums (value)
select top (1048576) 1
from master.sys.all_columns a cross join master.sys.all_columns b;
```

результат, возвращаемый запросом `/*1*/` с тем, что покажет `sp_spaceused`.

**Во-вторых**. Значение, возвращаемое `datalength` не всегда соответствует действительности. В частности, если `datalength([Column])` возвращает `NULL`, то физически это может быть вовсе не ноль.

Дело в том, что типы столбцов делятся на *fixed-length* (напр. `int`, `char(20)`, `datetime2(0)`, `uniqueidentifier`, и т.п.) и *variable-length* (напр. `varbinary(64)`, `nvarchar(30)` и т.п.). И если для variable-length оценка `/*1*/` приблизительно справедлива, то для fixed-length столбцов резервируется место для хранения значения, даже если само значение `NULL`.

Т.е. для fixed-length столбцов оценку `/*1*/` следует скорректировать, используя вместо `NULL` (если они возможны) какое-либо непустое значение, соответствующее типу столбца (например 0 для `int`):

```
/*2*/ select sum(datalength(isnull([IntColumn], 0))) from [Table];
```

Также нужно учитывать, что для столбцов типа `bit` возвращаемое `datalength` значение равно 1. Однако если в таблице (или индексе) несколько `bit` столбцов, то SqlServer объединяет их по 8 в 1 байт.

Также столбцы могут быть `sparse`, что означает 0 байт на хранение `NULL` (даже для fixed-length), но плюс 4 дополнительных байта на хранение значения, если оно не `NULL`:

```
/*3*/ select sum(datalength([SparseColumn]) + 4) from [TableName];
```

**В-третьих**. Если столбец не просто присутствует в таблице, а ещё и участвует в индексах, то он "утяжеляется" кратно количеству индексов, в которых он участвует. Если столбец является ключевым в кластерном индексе, то нужно прибавить оценку кратную количеству всех некластерных индексов (т.к. в leaf-level страницах некластерных индексов содержатся значения ключей кластерного  индекса). Так в таблице

```
create table SomeTable
(
    PK_ID bigint primary key,
    FK_1_ID int,
    FK_2_ID int,
    ...
    FK_10_ID int,
    UID uniqueidentifier
);

create index IX_1 on SomeTable (FK_1_ID);
...
create index IX_10 on SomeTable (FK_10_ID);
```

самым "тяжёлым" скорее всего окажется вовсе не `UID` столбец, а `PK_ID`, т.к. (помимо участия в кластерном первичном ключе) значения `PK_ID` будут присутствовать ещё в 10-ти некластерных индексах.

Следует учесть также, что если некластерный индекс является *фильтрованным индексом*, то соответствующую оценку (`/*1*/`, `/*2*/` или `/*3*/`) нужно взять не по всей таблице, а по строкам, соответствующим фильтру такого индекса.

**В-четвертых** (относится к Enterprise edition). Если применяется сжатие строк или страниц таблицы

```
alter table [TableName]
    rebuild partition = all with (data_compression = row);
```

либо индекса

```
alter index [IX_Name] on [TableName]
    rebuild with (data_compression = page);
```

то оценки с помощью `datalength` перестают быть адекватными и фактор "не менее чем" перестаёт работать.

Сравните для таблиц

```
create table strings (value char(2000));

insert into strings (value)
select top (10000) replicate('a', 2000)
from master.sys.all_columns a cross join master.sys.all_columns b;
```

и

```
create table strings_page (value char(2000)) with (data_compression = page);

insert into strings_page with (tablock) (value)
select top (10000) replicate('a', 2000)
from master.sys.all_columns a cross join master.sys.all_columns b;
```

значения оценки размера столбца с помощью `datalength` c тем, что покажет `sp_spaceused`. Для первой таблицы "показания" `datalength` и `sp_spaceused` будут близки (т.к. строка таблицы "широкая" и объем служебной информации сказывается мало), а для второй будут расходиться очень сильно.

**В-пятых**. Всё что было сказано до этого момента справедливо для SqlServer 2008. В более поздних версиях появились `COLUMNSTORE` индексы, которые, из-за особенностей своего устройства, могут хранить данные в существенно сжатом виде. Для них оценка размера столбца с помощью `datalength` также может давать неадекватный результат. Если для таблицы

```
create table strings_col (value char(2000));

insert into strings_col (value)
select top (10000) replicate('a', 2000)
from master.sys.all_columns a cross join master.sys.all_columns b;

create clustered columnstore index ix_clcs on strings_col;
```

сравнить показания `sp_spaceused` с `datalength`, то опять можно наблюдать сильное расхождение.

Полагаю, что данный список факторов, которые следует учитывать при оценке места, занимаемого тем или иным столбцом, не исчерпывающий.