# Как в SQL Server 2014 получить размеры записей в таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как в SQL Server 2014 получить размеры записей в таблице? Какой запрос нужно написать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, запросить статистику в `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` ([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188917.aspx)).

Запрос для случая, когда на таблице не используется *partitioning* (секционирование):

```
select
    ips.alloc_unit_type_desc,
    ips.record_count,
    min_record_size = ips.min_record_size_in_bytes,
    max_record_size = ips.max_record_size_in_bytes,
    avg_record_size = ips.avg_record_size_in_bytes
from
    sys.indexes ix
    cross apply sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(
        db_id(), ix.object_id, ix.index_id, NULL, 'SAMPLED') ips
where
    ix.object_id = object_id('dbo.TableName')
    and ix.type_desc in ('HEAP', 'CLUSTERED');
```

Если секционирование используется, то данные по разным секциям нужно агрегировать (среднее лучше взять взвешенное по количеству записей в секции):

```
select
    ips.alloc_unit_type_desc,
    record_count = sum(ips.record_count),
    min_record_size = min(ips.min_record_size_in_bytes),
    max_record_size = max(ips.max_record_size_in_bytes),
    avg_record_size =
        sum(ips.avg_record_size_in_bytes * ips.record_count) / sum(ips.record_count)
from
    sys.indexes ix
    cross apply sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(
        db_id(), ix.object_id, ix.index_id, NULL, 'SAMPLED') ips
where
    ix.object_id = object_id('dbo.TableName')
    and ix.type_desc in ('HEAP', 'CLUSTERED')
group by
    ips.alloc_unit_type_desc;
```

---

Обратите, однако, внимание. Если соответствующий запрос кроме строки с `alloc_unit_type_desc` равным `IN_ROW_DATA` возвращает также `LOB_DATA` или `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` с ненулевыми значениями (т.е. если в таблице есть LOB или variable-length столбцы с данными, из-за которых размер записи может превышать 8060 байт), то по данным возвращаемым `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` достоверно определить размеры записей таблицы не представляется возможным.

Дело в том, что одна запись таблицы физически может состоять из нескольких кусков (одного in-row и нескольких lob и row-overflow), но `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` не складывает данные по ним, а считает их отдельными "записями". Это можно видеть на следующем примере.

Если в таблицу с одним LOB столбцом вставить одну запись:

```
create table lob_test (data varbinary(max));
insert into lob_test values
    (cast(replicate(cast(0x11 as varbinary(max)), 32000) as varbinary(max)));
```

и посмотреть результат, который вернёт первый запрос для этой таблицы, то увидим

```
alloc_unit_type_desc  record_count  min_record_size  max_record_size  avg_record_size 
--------------------- ------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
IN_ROW_DATA           1             71               71               71
LOB_DATA              4             7894             8054             8014
```

т.е. единственная вставленная нами запись состоит из 1+4=5 кусков. В `LOB_DATA` не один кусок с `max_record_size` ~32 тыс. байт, а четыре куска по ~8 тыс. байт, что не позволяет правильно оценить размер записи.

Поэтому, в случаях, когда записи таблицы имеют данные в LOB или row-overflow страницах, целесообразнее может быть попытаться оценить размеры записей с помощью функции `datalength`:

```
select
    min_record_size = min(record.Size),
    max_record_size = max(record.Size),
    avg_record_size = avg(record.Size)
from dbo.TableName t
    cross apply (
        select
            datalength(Column1) +
            datalength(Column2) +
            ...
            datalength(ColumnN)) record(Size);
```

С `datalength`, однако, есть [подводные камни](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/560814/193999).