# Как вывести отчет по использованию памяти каждым столбцом в таблице MS SQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Мне нужно узнать, сколько весит каждый столбец в таблице. Могу для этого использовать

```
sum(datalength(столбец))
```

Но для каждого столбца это очень долго выводить, потому что таких столбцов десятки. Как просмотреть информацию о занимаемой памяти по каждому столбцу таблицы?

То есть в отчете я хочу видеть 2 столбца: название колонки и занимаемая память (отсортированные по памяти по убыванию)

Comment: большинство типов данных имеют фиксированный размер. у вас вариабельны будет только текстовые и бинарные данные неопределенной длины.

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/560814/193999).

Comment: от этого не меняется вопрос. текстовых столбцов также осталось много и также нужно вывести инфу о занимаемой памяти по ним

Comment: Какая у вас версия SQL Server? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: версия SQL v17.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Оно будет работать, начиная с SQL Server 2017 и более поздних версий.

**Дополнительные пояснения**

- SQL Server размещает таблицы на основе 8-килобайтных страниц. не
  на фактических размерах записей (rows).
- UPDATE/DELETE не работает in-place, они создают дополнительные
  фрагментации.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tbl;

CREATE TABLE tbl  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, city VARCHAR(20), State CHAR(2), Population INT, InsertedOn DATETIMEOFFSET(3) DEFAULT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET());
INSERT tbl (city, State, Population, InsertedOn) VALUES
('Miami', 'FL', 350000, Default),
('Orlando', 'FL', 300000, Default),
('Dallas', 'TX', 5000000, Default);
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

SELECT * FROM tbl;

DECLARE @tbl_catalog sysname = 'tempdb'
    , @tbl_name sysname = 'tbl'
    , @schema_name sysname = 'dbo'
    , @columnList VARCHAR(MAX)
    , @CrLf NCHAR(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
    , @Tab NCHAR(1) = NCHAR(9)
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- SQL Server 2017 onwards
SET @columnList = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),'='
        ,'SUM(DATALENGTH(',QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),'))',@CrLf,@Tab), ',')
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = @tbl_catalog
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema_name
        AND TABLE_NAME = @tbl_name
);

PRINT @columnList;

SET @SQL =
N';WITH rs(xmldata) AS
(
    SELECT ' + @columnList +
N'FROM tbl
    FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE, ROOT(''root'')
)
SELECT column_name = c.value(''local-name(.)'', ''SYSNAME'') 
    , column_value_bytes = c.value(''text()[1]'', ''INT'') 
FROM rs
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes(''/root/*'') AS t(c)
ORDER BY column_value_bytes DESC;';

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

**Результат**

| column_name | column_value_bytes |
| --- | --- |
| InsertedOn | 27 |
| city | 18 |
| ID | 12 |
| Population | 12 |
| State | 6 |

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!

Comment: Только почему в отчете "Использование дисковой памяти" пишет, что у меня таблица занимает 19 ГБ, а если просуммировать то, что получилось в выведенном запросе, у меня получается 15 ГБ?

Comment: то есть, где еще 4 ГБ?

Comment: @Makss123, в том то и дело, что sum(datalength(col)) даёт "логический" размер данных, а не физический.

Comment: пока не сел разбираться в чем отличие этих данных, можете мне на вопрос ответить?
То есть физический размер в цифрах всегда больше логического?

Comment: я добавил "Дополнительные пояснения" к ответу.

Comment: @Makss123, физический размер может быть и меньше логического (например, если применяется сжатие). Вообще там достаточное число нюансов (см. связанный вопрос). Я не встречал готового решения, которое бы всё учитывало.

Answer (score 0):

Если у таблицы есть **индексы**, то они тоже занимают какое-то место. Изредка суммарный объём индексов может превышать объём данных таблицы.

Если у Вас **таблица со сжатием** (на уровне СТРОК или на уровне СТРАНИЦ), то при некоторых ситуациях логический объём данных может превышать физический.

При вставке новой записи в таблицу, может произойти "расщепление" существующей 8k-страницы на две,- таким образом занимаемый объём таблицы вырастет не на "длину" записи а сразу на 8k. Поэтому, даже просуммировав длинну (в байтах) содержимого всех столбцов, можно получить только приблизительные объём. На диске данные базы данных хранятся (и обрабатываются в памяти MS SQL Server) экстентами - страницами по 8kbyte.